# the most accurate way to store date and time in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to store date and time in the database? I tried using `now()` on localhost: it works, but on live server it counts far back as 8 hours ago and current timestamp does the same thing. What is the most accurate approach?

```
$d="INSERT INTO `users`(`time`) VALUES (now())";
```

Comment: you can set a timezone right after you open your connection if you don't want to change the server time `SET time_zone = 'US/Eastern'`

Comment: that IS the most accurate method. general rule: if you doing date operations and the result is off by some exact multiple of 60 (hours, minutes) then it's almost ALWAYS a timezone issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the time in the most accurate method. It might not be in the correct timezone, but it is (as far as the server can tell) exactly that time when saved. If the timezone is incorrect, you will have to tell MySQL which timezone is considered "local" by executing something like `SET time_zone = 'YOUR_TIME_ZONE'` as soon as you open the connection.

A good trick to help with dealing with times is to make your storage layer only deal with times in UTC, and translate it to the local timezone in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you had wrong was your time zone

For example, use this :

SET time_zone = 'America/New_York';

with your time zone

Comment: Please how do i then autodetect user timezone cause my website is universal @Kavaliauskas Ivan

Comment: Please how do i then autodetect user timezone cause my website is universal @T0xicCode